# Use optaplanner for 3D bin packing with box rotation?

Tags: 3d, optaplanner, bin-packing

I am evaluating the http://www.optaplanner.org/ for solving a task of 3D bin packing. What is not clear for me - how can I configure the scorer/solver and the boxes to accept rotation of X,Y,Z axis?

Comment: Duplicates [this dev forum question](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/optaplanner-dev/ahz0i4tu5y0) which has an answer.